# Matriz como miembro de un objeto

Tags: c++, clase, matriz

He creado una clase Tramo, y como parte de los miembros existe una matriz dinámica m_puntual.

```
private:
        int m_id, m_maxPuntuales;
        float m_longitud, m_inercia, m_continua;
        float ** m_puntual;

void Tramo::setPuntual (float carga, float distancia, int indice)
{
    Tramo::m_puntual[indice][0] = carga;
    Tramo::m_puntual[indice][1] = distancia;
}
```

El constructor:

```
Tramo::Tramo(int id, float longitud, float inercia, float continua, int maxPuntuales)
{
    Tramo::m_id = id; // también válido this->m_id = id;
    Tramo::m_longitud = longitud;
    Tramo::m_inercia = inercia;
    Tramo::m_continua = continua;
    Tramo::m_maxPuntuales = maxPuntuales;
    Tramo::m_puntual = new float* [maxPuntuales];
    for (int p=0; p<maxPuntuales; p++)
    {
        Tramo::m_puntual [p] = new float [2]; //también vale this->m_puntual [p] = new float [2];
    }
}
```

Desde fuera de la clase, cada objeto creado tramo[i] puede tener diversas cargas puntuales:

```
std::cout << "Número de cargas puntuales: "; std::cin >> max_puntuales;
```

Cada carga puntual tendrá un valor carga y un valor distancia. Se rellenan los datos con este código:

```
for (int p=0; p<max_puntuales; p++)
{
            std::cout << "Carga puntual " << p+1 << ":" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\tValor: "; std::cin >> carga;
            std::cout << "\tDistancia al nudo izquierdo del tramo: "; std::cin >> dist_izq;
            tramo[i].setPuntual (carga, dist_izq, p);
}
```

Pero como resultado, todos los objetos tramo toman la carga y distancia del último objeto creado, en lugar de tener cada tramo sus propios datos.

¿En qué me falla el código?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

> ¿En qué me falla el código?

Probablemente sea un fallo que estés indexando los tramos con una variable diferente a la que usas en el bucle:

```
for (int p=0; p<max_puntuales; p++)
//       ^ <--- Bucle indexado con 'p'.
{
            std::cout << "Carga puntual " << p+1 << ":" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\tValor: "; std::cin >> carga;
            std::cout << "\tDistancia al nudo izquierdo del tramo: "; std::cin >> dist_izq;
            tramo[i].setPuntual (carga, dist_izq, p);
//                ^ <--- Datos indexados con 'i'.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No incluí el código completo de introducción de datos por simplificar la consulta, es éste:

```
for (int i=0; i<tramos_viga; i++)
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "DATOS DEL TRAMO " << i+1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Longitud: "; std::cin >> longitud;
    if (misma_seccion)
    {
        inercia = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        inercia = InerciaTramo();
    }
    std::cout << "Carga continua: "; std::cin >> continua;
    std::cout << "N\243mero de cargas puntuales: "; std::cin >> max_puntuales;
    tramo[i] = Tramo (i, longitud, inercia, continua, max_puntuales);   // usa el constructor de la clase Tramo para crear cada objeto tramo
    for (int p=0; p<max_puntuales; p++)
    {
        std::cout << "Carga puntual " << p+1 << ":" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tValor: "; std::cin >> puntual;
        std::cout << "\tDistancia al nudo izquierdo del tramo: "; std::cin >> dist_izq;
        tramo[i].setPuntual (p, puntual, dist_izq);
    }
}
```

En el código se ve que el índice "i" identifica cada nuevo objeto y el índice "p" identifica cada nueva carga en un mismo objeto.

Gracias por tu contestación, PaperBirdMaster

Comment: ¿Esta es una respuesta o es información complementaria de tu pregunta?, si es información complementaria recuerda que siempre puedes [Editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/527807/edit), esta sección es solo para respuestas que dan solución a tu problema. ;)